# Add "on duplicate key update" clause to insert into query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm starting with a query like this:

```
insert into summary ( col1, col2, Total ) 
select col1, col2, count(col4) as total from importdata 
where col1 = 'abc' and col4 in ('1A', '2A') 
group by col1, col2
order by col1, col2
```

and I haven't been able to determine how the correct 'on duplicate' clause. The clause I think I need is

```
on duplicate key update total=count(col4)
```

and I've placed it as the very last line in the query and as the line after the where clause, but both generated errors. Is my clause even correct and where does it need to go?

(Worst case I can use 'insert ignore', but I think doing the update would be better.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `COUNT` or other group functions in the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause. What you can do instead is this:

```
INSERT INTO summary ( col1, col2, Total ) 
    SELECT col1, col2, count(col4)
    FROM importdata 
    WHERE col1 = 'abc' AND col4 IN ('1A', '2A') 
    GROUP BY col1, col2
    ORDER BY col1, col2
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Total = VALUES(Total)
```

This says, if there is a duplicate key, instead of inserting a new row just set the column `total` to the value you would have inserted in `Total`. Note that I got rid of the `as total` -- that would have caused problems as you already have a column named `Total`, and the names are case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use functions for the duplicate key update, however, you could create a variable and then use that variable.

```
INSERT INTO summary (col1, col2, Total)
   select col1, col2,  @totalCount := count(col4) as Total from importdata 
   where col1 = 'abc' and col4 in ('1A', '2A') 
   group by col1, col2
   order by col1, col2
) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Total = @totalCount;
```